# nuxt.js generate static site with dynamic routes in netlify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, netlify

I'm trying to generate a static site with dynamic routes.

my **nuxt.config.js** looks like this:

```
const works = require('./static/works.json').map(item => '/work/' + item.slug)

export default {
  generate: {
    routes: works
  },
}
```

locally it works. everything is OK. but on netlify when run `npm run generate` returns this error: (and does not generate)

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
10:17:49 PM: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js: 1097: 14)
```

what happens?

Comment: You probably reference in your code localhost somewhere for fetching data

Comment: I am using the axios module in an index page and only this. -
async asyncData ({$ axios}) {
const works = await $ axios. $ get ('./works.json')
return {works}
}, how can this have to do with generate?

Comment: ye, and your base axios url is localhost unless u set differently. This is executed during generate so server from which u are getting data should be available

Comment: I'm feeling lost. according to the Axios module documentation "Automatically set base URL for client & server side". just to make it clear everything is working locally, the only problem is when I run npm run generate on netlify (returns the error that I quoted in the question). I really do not understand what I should do.

Comment: so when u run it locally some server is working that return your data. If your works.json is a local file why u  use axios to get it instead of importing and using like in in config?

Comment: I changed the $axios.$get ('./ works.json') to a require('~/static/works.json') in nuxt.config.js and on the index.vue page and it worked on netlify! besides your help, I read about it here https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/123 - I was using the axios module because that was what I read in the nuxt.js documentation. okay to use require instead of import?

Comment: In the issue you linked all your problem described as well as solutions. its fine to use to import your json file, just means if u change it you will need to rebuild your app.